# Skilled workers work permit (§ 18b ⑴ AufenthG) employer name deletion

Tags: germany, work-permit

In March 2022 I landed in Germany with a work contract beginning March 1.
In 2023 I was unemployed for 3 months and drew *Arbeitslosengeld*.
Then my previous company rehired me.

My *Zusatzbeiblatt* includes the employer’s name.
However, I expect becoming unemployed after February 2024 again.
So on March 1, 2024, I will have completed 24 months of legal stays.

Can I get my *Zusatzbeiblatt* changed so it omits the employer’s name?
Can I obtain a new *unrestricted* work permit?